# Can't call node.js function from HTML, 'clickPost is not defined'. Goal is to call the node.js function with HTML button

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im running node server.js which hosts this HTML. My goal is to call the function clickPost in that server.js file, or any other Javascript file. But it is saying that the function is undefined when I click the button at the bottom which should trigger it.

I have tried removing the  and replacing it with another JS file to rule out that one file but it does not work.

No error in the console when you press the button, but simply nothing happens. Its also not triggering the console.log() in the 'clickPost()' function.

Newer to JS and Node.js so it's probably something simple!

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" http-equiv="Content-Type">
            <!-- <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding"> -->

            <style>
        .flex-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          font-size: 30px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .green {
          background-color: green;
          padding: 10px;
          flex: auto;
        }

        .red {
          background-color: red;
          padding: 10px;
          flex: auto;
        }

        @media (max-width: 800px) {
          .left, .right {
            flex:100%;
          }
        }
  </style>
            <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
      function post(){
          var script = document.createElement("script");
          script.type = "text/javascript";
          script.src = "./post.js";
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
          return false;
      }
    </script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="server.js">
    </script>
            <title>hello test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Test for REST API Post - Click Green to POST 1</h1>
            <div class="flex-container">
                <div class="green" id=""></div>
         <button onclick="clickPost()">Click me</button>
                <div class="red" id="rightBox"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const cors = require('cors')


let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

let handleRequest = (request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            respone.write('Whoops! File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
};



http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(8000);

const body = {
  "name": "Test from HTML code :)",
  "description": "New Task Description"
};

function clickPost() {
  console.log("beep!")
  fetch('https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/list/67541785/task', {
        method: 'post',
        body:    JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'authkey', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
};
```

Comment: node runs on a server, html is in a browser

Comment: im running node server.js in a terminal and then loading this from localhost:8000, isn't that enough to run in the server Bravo? Otherwise what should I do? @Bravo

Comment: Or as a follow-up. Is there a good way to handle that API post without Node.js? I could not find a way without throwing it in the Node.js file.

Comment: @Bravo sorry i dont use SO very often. just making sure i tagged you correctly.

Comment: you say you can't "call nodejs function from HTML" - you are correct, you can't, it's impossible to do so - because HTML is on the browser, and nodejs is on the server - as I may have mentioned

Comment: You need to learn [about routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) and then call that route from your front-end code as an API call so that runs the function.

Comment: I see, thank you! Just a quick note, could I just use the fetch to POST to the API without using the server.js at all? Im not at a PC to test at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to call NodeJS functions directly from HTML, as HTML runs browser side and NodeJS is server based. The correct way to have HTML interact with NodeJS would be to create browser side functions using javascript that trigger an API call to your NodeJS

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a recommended source or idea for a browser side function to trigger an API call in my server.js file?

Comment: Sorry, I have never tried to do this in pure javascript so I can't be any help there. I'm sure there are plenty of resources available for you to access, however I would recommend looking into a javascript framework rather than using vanilla. Modules such as express make routing a LOT easier

Comment: I thought that modules like that were only available on Node JS and couldn't be used inside of HTML script. Will look into that, thanks!

Comment: it will make your server side routing easier, as for the frontend frameworks like React usually have methods that make it easier to perform external API calls

Comment: No need to use a library like React. Just write some JavaScript that [uses the fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to call the Express endpoint with the data.